# BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using python-build 2.2.5-11-gf0f2cdd1)

Tags: python, asdf

I have been trying to install python 3.9.1 in my local project with asdf
when trying to run `asdf install python 3.9.1` it returns this error.
I already tried to install the dependencies and still without success.

```
    asdf install python 3.9.1

python-build 3.9.1 /home/lucborges/.asdf/installs/python/3.9.1
Downloading Python-3.9.1.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/Python-3.9.1.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.1...

/home/lucborges/.asdf/plugins/python/pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 787: 77254 Killed                  ( if [ "${CFLAGS+defined}" ] || [ "${!PACKAGE_CFLAGS+defined}" ]; then
    export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS ${!PACKAGE_CFLAGS}";
fi; if [ -z "$CC" ] && is_mac -ge 1010; then
    export CC=clang;
fi; ${!PACKAGE_CONFIGURE:-./configure} --prefix="${!PACKAGE_PREFIX_PATH:-$PREFIX_PATH}" $CONFIGURE_OPTS ${!PACKAGE_CONFIGURE_OPTS} "${!PACKAGE_CONFIGURE_OPTS_ARRAY}" || return 1 ) 1>&4 2>&1

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using python-build 2.2.5-11-gf0f2cdd1)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20220401112545.77098
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220401112545.77098.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking sys/wait.h presence... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking pty.h usability... yes
checking pty.h presence... yes
checking for pty.h... yes
checking libutil.h usability... no
checking libutil.h presence... no
checking for libutil.h... no
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence...
```

Comment: me too facing the same issue

Comment: Likewise, facing the same issue.

Comment: were you able to solve this? having the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

you might need this to build:

> sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev